# Expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 in android for receiving data in json format from server and use it as an object. I am working on netbeans for server side. but it gives me the following exception that I mention above. This is my client (Android) code

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.6:8080/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    DriverClient driver = retrofit.create(DriverClient.class);
    Call<List<Driver>> call = driver.getDriverName();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Driver>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Driver>> call, Response<List<Driver>> response) {
            List<Driver> list = response.body();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Size : " + list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Driver driver = list.get(0);
            String name = driver.getName();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name : " + name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Driver>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error : " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Here is Driver class

```
public class Driver {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    public Driver(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and here is the DriverClient interface

```
public interface DriverClient {
    @GET("/Final/image")
    Call<List<Driver>> getDriverName();
}
```

This is simple server side code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("name", "Hafiz Hamza");    
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("chache-control", "no cache");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(json);
```

How to fix this exception

Comment: Your server code is generating JSON from a *single object*, but your client code wants a `List`, aka a JSON *array*, which is *exactly* what the **error message is telling you**: The JSON is an object *("was begin_object")*, and you're trying to parse it as an array *("expected begin_array")*. Which part of this is confusing you? --- To fix: Change one or the other, i.e. either change server to generate a list, or change client to expect an object. Which part of *this* is confusing you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an `object` from your endpoint, hence expect an `object` in your app side(here you are expecting an `array` from app side)

Try this

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.6:8080/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
DriverClient driver = retrofit.create(DriverClient.class);
Call<Driver> call = driver.getDriverName();

call.enqueue(new Callback<Driver>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Driver> call, Response<Driver> response) {
        Driver driver = response.body();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Size : " + list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String name = driver.getName();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name : " + name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Driver> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error : " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

and your api interface

```
public interface DriverClient {
@GET("/Final/image")
Call<Driver> getDriverName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it means that the response result is one object but you call for list.
 Change  Call> to Call